# Getting Exception : StringIndexOutofBoundsException

Tags: android, json, google-sheets

I am implementing an Android app. I have a Google Spreadsheet with about 100 rows of data ( with 2 columns). I am fetching data from this spreadsheet to my app.
[This is my spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tq&key=1n_VjwHm8qIU5YRMM-wMkJIap2KZa5vOfxWI5dpYT1PE&gid=1262286779)
But, I am getting this exeption `StringIndexOutofBoundsException.`

`Main Activity`

```
// action bar
private ActionBar actionBar;

private ListView listView;

ListAdapter adapter;

DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

DBHelper dbHelper;

Utility utility;

ArrayList<Personinfo> list;

ArrayAdapter<Personinfo> arrayAdapter;

AdapterFilter adapterfilter;

LinearLayout linearLayout;

Personinfo personinfo;

Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

Intent intent;

// private static final String FETCH_DATA_FROM_SPREADSHEET =
// "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FJBt8ZHAcnfwLhx0rYjC4ELImLInYxkOTTauw8PL6W4/gviz/tq";
private static final String FETCH_DATA_FROM_SPREADSHEET = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tq&key=1n_VjwHm8qIU5YRMM-wMkJIap2KZa5vOfxWI5dpYT1PE&gid=1262286779";

/** The pref name. */
final String PREF_NAME = "pref";

/** The hash map. */
public static HashMap<Integer, List<String>> hashMap = null;

/** The info array list. */
public static ArrayList<String> infoArrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#03A9F4")));
    actionBar.setTitle("Agarwal Association");

    list = new ArrayList<Personinfo>();

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    dbHelper.openDataBase();
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.Get_ContactDetails();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String name = cursor.getString(0);
        String phoneno = cursor.getString(1);
        Personinfo personinfo = new Personinfo(name, phoneno);
        list.add(personinfo);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
    dbHelper.close();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapterfilter = new AdapterFilter(this, R.layout.child_listview, list);
    Log.i("List", "" + list.get(0).getPhoneno());

    listView.setAdapter(adapterfilter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    getSpreadSheetData();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapterfilter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            adapterfilter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            adapterfilter.getFilter().filter(query);
            adapterfilter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        // search action
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void getSpreadSheetData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
    // hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    String result = getSpreadSheetResponce();

    Log.i("jsonResponse:", result);
    System.out.print(result);

    // remove the unnecessary parts from the response and construct a
    // JSON
    int start = result.indexOf("{", result.indexOf("{") + 1);
    int end = result.lastIndexOf("}");
    System.out.println("Start: " + start + " End: " + end
            + " results length: " + result.length());
    String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);

    try {
        JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        // String value = null;
        List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (mainObj != null) {
            JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("rows");
            if (list != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject innerJsonObject = list.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (innerJsonObject != null) {
                        JSONArray valuesJsonArray = innerJsonObject
                                .getJSONArray("c");
                        if (valuesJsonArray != null) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < valuesJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject innerElem = valuesJsonArray
                                        .getJSONObject(j);
                                if (innerElem != null) {
                                    String name = innerElem.getString("v");
                                    String phoneno = innerElem
                                            .getString("f");
                                    arraylist.add(name);
                                    arraylist.add(phoneno);
                                    hashMap.put(j, arraylist);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.i("hashMap.get(0)", "" + hashMap.get(0));
        infoArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        infoArrayList.addAll(hashMap.get(0));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getSpreadSheetResponce() {
    URL url;
    String responce = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(FETCH_DATA_FROM_SPREADSHEET);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream()));
        while ((responce = in.readLine()) != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        Log.i("Responce:", "" + in);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responce;
}
```

`LogCat`

```
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.agrawalassociation/com.example.agrawalassociation.SearchActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; regionStart=-1; regionLength=0
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; regionStart=-1; regionLength=0
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at com.example.agrawalassociation.SearchActivity.getSpreadSheetData(SearchActivity.java:179)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at com.example.agrawalassociation.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:117)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
08-24 12:52:18.747: E/AndroidRuntime(14543):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; regionStart=-1; regionLength=0
```

You're trying to take a substring starting at position -1. In other words, your *start* variable has the value -1.

-1 is what indexOf() returns when it wasn't able to find what you were looking for. It probably failed because your *result* string does not look as you expected (or your double-indexOf() calls logic is faulty).

*EDIT:* Your linked "spreadsheet" ("json.txt") starts with this line: `/*O_o*/`. Seven characters, no braces... that's probably the one that's tripping your code up.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem occured in  `String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);`

should be using `if(result.length > 0)` to avoid the exception

Comment: and using logcat to print the values of **result.length**,**start** and **end**  to check it out.

Comment: The exception stack trace says that the String's length is 7 -- so checking `result.length() > 0` would make no difference.

Comment: Yup. The problem seems to be that the `result` string does not look like @abc expected (there were no braces).

Comment: but in my response result I am getting braces still it is showing this exception @SnildDolkow

Comment: I don't think that's true -- I think you're missing something. Your code is logging the `result` variable. Would you please post that part of the log? Actually, I can see the problem from your linked file... I'll make an update to my answer.